# pandas: max column value for each datetime (index) cluster with intra-cluster distance <= N minutes

Tags: pandas, datetime

If a dataframe has a datetime index with, in this example, 6 clusters (a cluster is defined here as rows where no two adjacent rows have a datetime difference > 10 minutes), how can I select the 6 rows of the dataframe which hold the max column value in each of these 6 clusters?

Here's the input dataframe:

```
                           throughput_ins
ts                                                        
2021-05-03 08:45:00-07:00            16.0
2021-05-03 08:46:00-07:00            16.0
2021-05-03 08:47:00-07:00            17.0
2021-05-03 12:30:00-07:00            11.0
2021-05-03 12:32:00-07:00            12.0
2021-05-03 12:34:00-07:00            13.0
2021-05-03 12:36:00-07:00            16.0
2021-05-03 13:01:00-07:00            13.0
2021-05-03 13:02:00-07:00            17.0
2021-05-03 13:06:00-07:00            24.0
2021-05-03 13:07:00-07:00            14.0
2021-05-03 14:48:00-07:00            17.0
2021-05-03 14:49:00-07:00            15.0
2021-05-03 14:50:00-07:00            18.0
2021-05-03 14:58:00-07:00            24.0
2021-05-03 14:59:00-07:00            26.0
2021-05-03 15:00:00-07:00            27.0
2021-05-03 15:04:00-07:00            31.0
2021-05-03 15:08:00-07:00            39.0
2021-05-03 15:09:00-07:00            34.0
2021-05-03 15:10:00-07:00            28.0
2021-05-03 15:58:00-07:00            10.0
2021-05-03 16:00:00-07:00            11.0
2021-05-03 17:20:00-07:00            13.0
2021-05-03 17:21:00-07:00            18.0
2021-05-03 17:22:00-07:00            17.0
```

And here is the expected output dataframe:

```
                           throughput_ins
ts                                                        
2021-05-03 08:47:00-07:00            17.0
2021-05-03 12:36:00-07:00            16.0
2021-05-03 13:06:00-07:00            24.0
2021-05-03 15:08:00-07:00            39.0
2021-05-03 16:00:00-07:00            11.0
2021-05-03 17:21:00-07:00            18.0
```

I thought using `df.groupby` + `iloc` would be the way but I'm not sure how to code the `adjacent rows < 10 minutes` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cumsum()` of the condition to find the block, then `groupby().idxmax` to find the rows with max values:

```
blocks = df.index.to_series().diff().gt(pd.Timedelta('10T')).cumsum()
max_rows = df.groupby(blocks)['throughput_ins'].idxmax()
df.loc[max_rows]
```

Output:

```
                           throughput_ins
ts                                       
2021-05-03 08:47:00-07:00            17.0
2021-05-03 12:36:00-07:00            16.0
2021-05-03 13:06:00-07:00            24.0
2021-05-03 15:08:00-07:00            39.0
2021-05-03 16:00:00-07:00            11.0
2021-05-03 17:21:00-07:00            18.0
```